# Ads - Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cors, access-control

I am seeing this error via Google inspect on my Wordpress website.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at (ad lines I have removed) from origin
> 'https://www.awakenthegreatnesswithin.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

I saw this last week. I added this to the .htaccess file in the root of the domain:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
        Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none"
        Header set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "unsafe-none"
        Header set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy "cross-origin"
        Header set X-Download-Options "noopen"
        Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
        Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    </IfModule>
```

I also added this to .htaccess in the public_html

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

Last week the Ads on my site were not showing great but now I would say 90% usually show, sometimes 100% but I still see the error via Google inspect even though the Ads are showing

Can someone help me to understand what caused this? As I have never had any problems like this before, and what can I do to get rid of this error message?

Is this something I need to fix on my end? Or my Ad Network need to adjust something on their end?

Thank you

Updated PHP to (8+) was the only major change

Comment: ".htaccess file in the root of the domain" / ".htaccess in the public_html" - Is `public_html` not the root directory? Where is your WP site installed (which is the WP `.htaccess` file)?

Comment: "Or my Ad Network..." - This is really an issue with your ad network, it is there that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is "missing". The only thing you can do is if you should be sending some particular HTTP request header as part of the initial request?

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the detailed explanation

Comment: ".htaccess file in the root of the domain" / ".htaccess in the public_html" - Is public_html not the root directory? Where is your WP site installed (which is the WP .htaccess file)? – 
MrWhite ------ I thought the main file on the hosting server is the root? That's what they told me in Siteground